# Automatic Authentication--Google Calendar API

Tags: python, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I have more of a general question about how I would go about achieving something. I would like to run a daemon process that updates my own Google Calendar (as a background process). I have consulted the sites regarding Google API procedure (authentication, access tokens, etc.) and it seems that the authentication code I've seen requires manual authentication on my part (i.e. me pressing the 'yes, i'm okay with this application accessing my calendar' button). Given that I am writing a program to access my own google calendar (so security shouldn't be an issue), is there any way I can authenticate from within my own source code (perhaps a way of including my login info within the Python script I am writing for this program)?

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to Service Account with OAuth2.0. (See here : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) It will provide a service account for your application, from which you will be able to handle calendars for your app.

I know it's possible to do it using java and here you will find a sample showing how to do it with Java. (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts)

And I am almost sure it's also possible with Python. (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)