# Is there any way to connect my google calendar to google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-calendar-api

I created a project using the Google Cloud Console and created an OAuth screen. But when I used Python in colab to access the calendar, I got an error message that I don't have a proper redirect uri. Is there any way to bypass accessing my Google Calendar with my login credentials rather than using an access token

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517911/automatic-authentication-google-calendar-api) might be related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login in Google Colab with Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798776/login-in-google-colab-with-oauth2)